# create substring column in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to take a json file and map it so that one of the columns is a substring of another. For example to take the left table and produce the right table:

```
 ------------              ------------------------
|     a      |             |      a     |    b    |
|------------|       ->    |------------|---------|
|hello, world|             |hello, world|  hello  |
```

I can do this using spark-sql syntax but how can it be done using the in-built functions?

Comment: Will column a always be two words delimited by a comma? And will column b always be the first word?

Comment: no and no, ideally the solution should run a substring function over column a values to produce column b

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Such statement can be used

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

`dataFrame.select(col("a"), substring_index(col("a"), ",", 1).as("b"))`

Comment: Do you have any syntax reference for above code..I am not able to understand the syntax part of it. Thanks!

Comment: Spark functions "col", "substring_index" are used. Functions described here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html

Answer (score 12):

Suppose you have the following dataframe:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

var df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("foobar", "foo"))).toDF("a", "b")

+------+---+
|     a|  b|
+------+---+
|foobar|foo|
+------+---+
```

You could subset a new column from the first column as follows:

```
df = df.select(col("*"), substring(col("a"), 4, 6).as("c"))

+------+---+---+
|     a|  b|  c|
+------+---+---+
|foobar|foo|bar|
+------+---+---+
```

Answer (score 6):

You would use the `withColumn` function

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{ udf, col }
def substringFn(str: String) = your substring code
val substring = udf(substringFn _)
dataframe.withColumn("b", substring(col("a"))
```

Comment: UDFs are bad because, depending on what you do in them, the query planner/optimizer may not be able to "see through" it.

Comment: @JonWatte This is a good point. Keep in mind that there are some cases when the functions that spark provide are not enough, for instance: converting long/lat columns into a geohash.

Answer (score 6):

Just to enrich existing answers. In case you were interested in the right part of the string column. That is:

```
 ------------              ------------------------
|     a      |             |      a     |    b    |
|------------|       ->    |------------|---------|
|hello, world|             |hello, world|  world  |
```

You should use a negative index:

```
dataFrame.select(col("a"), substring_index(col("a"), ",", -1).as("b"))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just do it by using the `pyspark` way, like in the following example:

```
df.withColumn('New_col', df['Old_col'].substr(0, 7)).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get substring from the beginning of string then count their index from 0, where letter 'h' has 7th and letter 'o' has 11th index:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import substring
df = df.withColumn('b', col('a').substr(7, 11))
```

if you want to get last 5 strings and word 'hello' with length equal to 5 in a column, then use:

```
df = df.withColumn('b', col('a').substr(-5,5))
```